# convert timestamp string into datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have a column of dates in this undesirable string format of 'Sun May  1 00:00:10 2016', representing 'Weekday, Mon, Day, hh:mm:ss, Year'.

How can I can format this using pandas.to_datetime or numpy?

Appreciate the help!

```
import pandas as pd

date = 'Sun May  1 00:00:10 2016'
df = pd.DataFrame([date], columns=['date'])
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame([pd.to_datetime(date)], columns=['date'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for this type of tasks you should use `strptime` method from `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
s = 'Sun May 1 00:00:10 2016'
f = '%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
dt.strptime(s, f)
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0, 10)
```

As far as `pandas` is concerned:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":
                  ['Sun May 1 00:00:10 2016','Sun May 2 00:00:10 2016']})
df
date
0   Sun May 1 00:00:10 2016
1   Sun May 2 00:00:10 2016


df.date.apply(lambda s: dt.strptime(s,f))
0   2016-05-01 00:00:10
1   2016-05-02 00:00:10
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**EDIT**

To make it more complete, the way suggested by `user1753919` in comment to your question is also "just works" in this case:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date)
0   2016-05-01 00:00:10
1   2016-05-02 00:00:10
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However, the results of timing might be of interest:

```
%timeit df.date.apply(lambda s: dt.strptime(s,f))
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.date)
1000 loops, best of 3: 369 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 771 µs per loop
```

Comment: your timing results are completely misleading; try with a larger number